# How to reverse laravel gulp webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, gulp, webpack

Like the title says. I made a mistake and my js got replaced by webpack and didn't keep the old file. Is there a way to reverse the webpack? Or at least so it is a lot more readible. Right now it is probaly to much work to reverse the work.

**UPDATE**
I keep getting the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flag

The code I'm using right now is:

```
var unpack = require('browser-unpack');
var rows = unpack('/js/games/spot-the-difference.js');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").text(rows);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a npm-bundle called [browser-unpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-unpack) that should suit your needs.

1. Install the package via `npm install browser-unpack`
2. Create a javascript file to unpack your wanted .js file

   ```
   var unpack = require('browser-unpack');
   var rows = unpack('pathToYourSource');
   //Write your rows to file then or do sth else here.
   ```
3. Execute your file by using `node pathToYourFile.js`

Comment: Could you maybe shed some more light on how to use browser-unpack?

Comment: @user3398922 Done ;)

Comment: Updated the question since I keep getting the same error. Really thanks for all the help